# Query time column from postgresql using jdbc

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm using **PostgreSQL 8.4**, and the server is linux, and the linux's time zone `is'EDT`' not '`UTC`'. The configuration of **PostgreSQL** make the DataBase's time zone to 'UTC'. The code is running on **JBoss9**.

I have one sql, `select to_char(ts_entry.submitted_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MM') as submitted_date_format from ts_entry where ....`

If we run the sql in **PostgreSQL**, we will get the value, "`07/10/2017 02:07`"

But when I try to get the value from `resultSet` in java,

```
Statement st = connection.createStatement(); 
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql); 
String value = rs.getString("submitted_date_format");
```

The value will be "`07/09/2017 22:07`".
The origin value in DB is "`2017-07-10 02:02:25.268+00`".

How can I handle the effect caused by linux server's timezone in code level?

BTW, I know an alternative solution, change the start up scripts of jboss, to make the jboss to start up using timezone 'UTC'. Can this issue be handled in code level?

Comment: java's `LocalDateTime` should be able to do the magic

Comment: But the value type in resultSet is 'String'

Comment: if the database column is date/datetime, then it will have something like date or timestamp in resultset

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it, the column type in DB is timestamp, but I want to get the formatted date, not the origin value. And the formatted date is 'String', the origin value is 'timestamp'

Comment: take the original value, convert it to a `java.util.Date` then call `d.setHours(d.getHours()-4);` and then parse it to a string

Comment: only thing i am wondering is where the +5 mins come from

Comment: Sorry, can't do it. I need someting like 'select ... from ... where submitted_date_formatted like '%2017%''. So if the formatted date string is wrong in SQL result, I will not be able to do further filter.

Comment: what you are saying makes no sense. try to make clear what exactly you want to do as you are making contradictory statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Database server machine's time zone has no direct impact on the behaviour, except that it is used to initialize `timezone` in `postgresql.conf`, which is the initial setting for the client time zone unless overridden by the database session.

PostgreSQL stores `timestamp with time zone` in UTC internally and converts it to the client's local time zone upon delivery.

So you should set the database session time zone the way you need with

```
SET TIME ZONE '<time zone name>';
```

That will convert dates to that time zone when you select then from PostgreSQL.

Comment: Yes, what you said makes sense. But if 2 clients use the same server, and both will retrieve the same data. So I need to convert the same data into different time zone, and I can get different clients' time zone,but the linux server's time zone will ruin all these.

Comment: The *default* Java time zone is set by the client operating system time zone, but nothing keeps you from explicitly using different time zones in your code.

Comment: I debugged the code using IntelliJ, remote connected to linux server. and the String value is wrong `"07/09/2017 22:07"` BTW, my developing environment's time zone is -8 hours, and the linux server's time zone is -4 hours, and the String value is -4 hours to origin value, so my developing environment seems to have no affect on the value.

Comment: I have investigated some more and changed the answer. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is the solution.

Comment: It's similar. I wrote a function, `tochar(_value VARCHAR, _timezone VARCHAR)` the body of the fucntion is `set time zone _timezone; return to_char(_value);`